# React Native TypeScript Stack Navigator Usage

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation, navigator, stack-navigator

I'm not writing here to ask a question...
I'm new to React Native and didn't know TypeScript or JavaScript at all.
In React Native, stack screens were working in JS but not in TSX. I did a long research, but I could not come across a simple application designed to understand the logic. I wanted to leave one here so that anyone who needs it like me can look at it without having to search for hours. Here are my codes.

App.tsx //

```
import NavigationRouter from './src/navigation/types/NavigationRouter';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <NavigationRouter/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

NavigationRouter.tsx // Our Navigation Screen

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from '../../scrrens/Home';
import Profile from '../../scrrens/Profile';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const NavigationRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default NavigationRouter

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

StackParamList.ts // Our type folder

```
type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    Profile: undefined;
  };
```

Home.tsx

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from "@react-navigation/native-stack"; 

type HomeProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList,'Home'>;

const Home:React.FC<HomeProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button 
        title='Profil'
        onPress= { () => navigation.navigate('Profile')}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Profile.tsx

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from "@react-navigation/native-stack"; 

type ProfileProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;

const Profile:React.FC<ProfileProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Profil</Text>
      <Button 
        title='geridon'
        onPress= { () => navigation.navigate('Home')}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Profile

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

**Explanation;**

1. *App.tsx*
   We must call our navigations in `'<NavigationContainer>'` if dont they are not navigatin.
2. *NavigationRouter.tsx*
   We need this for screens can know each other. Additionally, by casting types to this stack, we can write them appropriately in TypeScript.
   `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();`
3. *StackParamList*
   Type for screen and props search for more type script props
4. *Home|Profile.tsx*
   we need to define new type like
   `"type HomeProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList,'Home'>;"`
   We assign the NativeStackScreenProps to the "home" within our RootStackParamList types
   then we can cast it out our const
   `"Home:React.FC<HomeProps>"` like this

I try to make a navigation whit react native but when i try to access navigation.navigate it didnt work so i m noticed i m useing type script and it is type secure i need to define the type befor usage .